# In OAuth 2.0, what is the difference between a grant and a flow?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I have been reading through the OAuth 2.0 spec and I can't figure out the difference between a grant and a flow. The documentation seems to use the terms interchangeably. Grants are defined [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3).

For example, consider the following snippet taken directly from the spec:

```
The implicit grant is a simplified authorization code flow optimized for clients...
```

Why didn't they say

`implicit flow is a simplified authorization code flow optimized for clients...`

? Can someone please explain what the difference is between a grant and a flow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `flow` is more generic and refers to the whole protocol that allows the access token issuance.

The `authorization grant` refers only to the credentials used during the flow (authorization code, client credentials...).